# Transfering field values from a table to a featureclass using multiple cursors

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcgis, arcpy

I have a feature class that I am updating selected rows using a table of updated values. I have a script that uses calculate field but I am looking to see if using cursors will increase performance. The script runs with no errors but the data is not being written to the feature class.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

target = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']
source = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']


featureclass = r'C:DATA\name.gdb\featureclass'
table = r'C:DATA\valueTable.csv'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, source) as source_cursor:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureclass, target) as update_cursor:
        for update_row in update_cursor:
            for source_row in source_cursor:
                if source_row[0] == update_row[0]:
                    for n in range(len(source)):
                        update_row[n] = source_row[n]
                        update_cursor.updateRow(update_row)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

No data is in the fields in the feature class when I open ArcGIS to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works if `target` and `source` has the same number of records and the records are ordered the exact same way.

If this is not applying, then you'll have to iterate over the records of `source` `N` times, whereas `N` is the number of records in `target`.

However, your `source_cursor` is most likely (depending on the records' order) exhausted. Therefore, you have no data. You'll need to [reset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm#M2_GUID-3CB1DFF4-983D-445F-9CB2-0FF1CD4B4880) the cursor with `source_cursor.reset()`.

You'll also want to correct the indentation of `update_cursor.updateRow(update_row)`. There is also an error in the paths: `C:DATA...`.

```py
import arcpy

# no need for: arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

target = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']
source = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']

featureclass = r'C:\DATA\name.gdb\featureclass'
table = r'C:\DATA\valueTable.csv'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, source) as source_cursor:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureclass, target) as update_cursor:
        for update_row in update_cursor:
            for source_row in source_cursor:
                if source_row[0] == update_row[0]:
                    for n in range(len(source)):
                        update_row[n] = source_row[n]

                    # corrected indentation
                    update_cursor.updateRow(update_row)

            # add this line:
            source_cursor.reset()
```

**Please note:** I haven't tested your code and wrote all code in this answer from memory!

Source:

- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

---

Since both cursors using the same fields, no need to assign fields individually:

```py
import arcpy

target = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']
source = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']

featureclass = r'C:\DATA\name.gdb\featureclass'
table = r'C:\DATA\valueTable.csv'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, source) as source_cursor:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureclass, target) as update_cursor:
        for update_row in update_cursor:
            for source_row in source_cursor:
                if source_row[0] == update_row[0]:

                    # corrected indentation AND using source_row
                    update_cursor.updateRow(source_row)

            # add this line:
            source_cursor.reset()
```

---

Depending on how many records `source` has, it could be worth reading the record once and storing them in memory using a dictionary.

This would of course not be feasible if you have a huge number of records and little memory.

```py
import arcpy

target = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']
source = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']

featureclass = r'C:\DATA\name.gdb\featureclass'
table = r'C:\DATA\valueTable.csv'

source_records = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, source) as source_cursor:
    for row in source_cursor:
        source_records[row[0]] = row

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureclass, target) as update_cursor:
    for row in update_cursor:
        source_record = source_records.get(row[0])
        if source_record:
            update_cursor.updateRow(source_record)
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use `where_clause`. However, I don't think that is more performant as it creates a cursor for `source` `N` times.

```py
import arcpy

target = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']
source = ['JoinField', 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldn']

featureclass = r'C:\DATA\name.gdb\featureclass'
table = r'C:\DATA\valueTable.csv'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureclass, target) as update_cursor:
    for row in update_cursor:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, source,
                             where_clause=f"JoinField={row[0]}") as source_cursor:

            first_row = next(source_cursor)
            update_cursor.updateRow(first_row)
```

---

I hope that helps.